# How to fix c++ indentation in emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs

I have been trying to setup a c++ environment in emacs, and one of the main problems which I have faced has been trying to get the indentation the way I like it:

By default emacs will make `private:` and `public:` be indented to the beginnning of the line when I am making a class:

```
class Main {
private:
public:
};
```

I would like it not to indent these at all and leave them as is:

```
class Main {
    private:
    public:
};
```

As well as this I would also like to fix this weird issue where emacs will indent the code forward and back when I am trying to refer to a namespace:

```
int main()  {
   std:
}
```

and then as soon as I have finished adding the second colon it will go back to the normal indentation level I would expect:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
}
```

Comment: I have tried making my own custom style  and changing things like offset for the access-label however I still can't get it working.

Comment: Try the `java` style: I think it does what you want for the private/public case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating my own c-style and customizing the offset for the `access-label` and `label` syntactic symbols:

```
(c-add-style "my-c-style" '((c-tab-always-indent . t)
                            (c-basic-offset . 4)
                            (c-offsets-alist (access-label . 0)
                                             (label . +))))
;; Setting this as the default style:
(setq c-default-style "my-c-style")
```